# Using RunAs in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell script to run a quick HitmanPro scan on computers. I have deployed this script through GFI RMM and while it works, I need to pass it domain administrator information.

```psh
$HitmanParameters = "/scanonly /quick /noinstall /quiet"
$AgentPath = (${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}, ${env:ProgramFiles} -ne $null)[0]

if (Test-Path "$AgentPath\Advanced Monitoring Agent") {
    $AgentPath="$AgentPath\Advanced Monitoring Agent"
} elseif (Test-Path "$AgentPath\Advanced Monitoring Agent GP") { 
    $AgentPath="$AgentPath\Advanced Monitoring Agent GP"
} else {
    Write-Host "Agent Path Not Found"
}

if (-not (Test-Path "$AgentPath\HitmanPro")) {
    Write-Host "Creating Hitman Folder"
    [system.io.directory]::CreateDirectory("$AgentPath\HitmanPro")
}

$HitmanParameters = "$HitmanParameters /log=""$AgentPath\HitmanPro\results.txt"""

if (-not (Test-Path "$AgentPath\HitmanPro\HitmanPro.exe")) {
    Write-Host "HitmanPro Not found"

    if ($(Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor WHERE  AddressWidth='64'")) {
        $HMPURL = "http://dl.surfright.nl/HitmanPro_x64.exe"
    } else {
        $HMPURL = "http://dl.surfright.nl/HitmanPro.exe"
    }

    Write-Host "Downloading $HMPURL ..."
    $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $webClient.DownloadFile($HMPURL,"$AgentPath\HitmanPro\HitmanPro.exe")

    if (Test-Path "$AgentPath\HitmanPro\HitmanPro.exe") {
        Write-Host "Download Complete!"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Error Downloading Hitman Pro"
    }
}

if (Test-Path "$AgentPath\HitmanPro\HitmanPro.exe") {
    Write-Host "Running HitmanPro Scan..."
    Write-Host "HitmanPro.exe $HitmanParameters"

    Start-Process -FilePath "$AgentPath\HitmanPro\HitmanPro.exe" -ArgumentList  "$HitmanParameters" -NoNewWindow -Wait

    If (Test-Path "$AgentPath\HitmanPro\results.txt") {
        $data = Get-Content -Encoding Unicode   "$AgentPath\HitmanPro\results.txt"
        remove-item "$AgentPath\HitmanPro\results.txt"

        foreach ($line in $data) {
            If($line.contains("Threats")) {
                $Infections = [int] $line.Split(":")[1]

                If($Infections -eq 0) {
                    Write-Host "No Infections Found"
                    $data
                    exit 0
                    break
                } Else {
                    Write-Host "Infections Found!"
                    $data
                    exit 1000
                    break
                }
            } #If Line contains Threats
        } #ForEach
    } Else {
        Write-Host "No Logfile Found"!
    } #LogFile Found
} Else { 
    Write-Host "HitmanPro Still Not Found!"
}#HitmanPro Found
```

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: It is being run remotely through GFI's remote management dashboard. It runs like it should but runs under a system account and I would prefer to run under a domain admin account.

Comment: Why? If it works fine with a system account, don't bother. There's nothing to be gained from switching to a domain admin account when the script doesn't require the additional privileges of such an account.

Comment: Will the system account have access to the user folders and shares? I apologize for all the questions kind of new to all this.

Comment: The SYSTEM account has only access to local resources. However, files on shares should be checked on the fileserver anyway.